Python UltrasSonic Sensor
AJ-SR04M
How’s it going. I’m going to try and limit this for simplicity. I am a student studying EE. I have an UltraSonic Sensor connected using USB Serial Port CH340. I have tried to look for a python script that could give the distance but it seems it’s not possible. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.
I have tried looking online but no help

more or less this is hardware oriented, question how to read from serial port using python is aldready answered here, search for it. and how to process the input to give distance is hardware oriented, you can check out arduino forumn for guidance on how to change serial read to distance

few sensor directly give out distance in utf-8 through serial port,for others you need to do further processing,calculations

Do you know what forums I can look into?

is ultrasonic sensor connected directly through usb no microcontroller?, which sensor do you use?

I'm using [AJ-SR04] Ultrasonic Sonic Sensor and HW597 CH340 USB to TTL. I have looked into these forums and wrote this code

https://tutorials.probots.co.in/communicating-with-a-waterproof-ultrasonic-sensor-aj-sr04m-jsn-sr04t/?amp=1
